# write.table in R generates an empty file

Tags: r, file-io, text-files

I have a data frame in an object with large number of rows and columns. I wish to write it in a file, so I do this,

```
> write.table(object, file="file.txt")
```

But I don't know for what reason this is giving me an empty file. I thought may be because write.table does not handle such large data (800 columns and 450,000 rows). So I tried the following.

```
> write.table(object[1:4,1:5], file="file.txt")
```

But I still get an empty file. I checked my object. It does contain all the data i need.

Can anyone help me know why I may be getting an empty file? Is there any other way to get my object data into a file?

Comment: Please provide a small sample of your actual `object` , for example, the result of `object[1:4,1:5]` .  And just for the heck of it, make sure you have full file permissions in your working directory.

Comment: I am sorry for the trouble, but i just realised what was the problem. I was working with R through a server and it was running out of memory for my data. So I deleted a few files and ran the "write.table" command again. And now it works fine.. Thank you for your help though.. :)

Comment: @PoojaMandaviya you should write this as an answer rather than a comment.  That will make it easier for future people with the same issue to solve their problem.  And you should accept your anser so we don't spend time trying to solve a solved problem.  :-)

Comment: Yes you are right. I put it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry for the trouble, but i just realised what was the problem. I was working with R through a server and it was running out of memory for my data. So I deleted a few files and ran the "write.table" command again. And now it works fine.. Thank you for your help though.. :)

Comment: I think you should accept this as the answer so that the question remains solved.

Comment: I was running a script file on a server and write.table was performing erratically.  This turned out to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but you can try to convert your list into a dataframe. Then you can create a CSV file with your dataframe.

```
df_last<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, object))
write.table(df_last, file = "foo.csv", sep = ",")
```

Comment: I just tried this as well.. I still get an empty file. It never happened before. I don't understand why.

Comment: As carl mentioned, can you tell us what is in your `object`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
object <- data.frame(a = I("a \" quote"), b = pi)
write.table(object, file = "foo.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA,
        qmethod = "double")
```

Do you get `foo.csv` file created?

Comment: what do you get when you do `typeof(object)` in your R shell?